# Is it possible to have python functions with "inheritance"?

Tags: python, oop

Im trying to create a "function with inheritance" so that I dont have to have a bunch of similar functions with copy pasted code. And this is effectively what I ended up with:

```
class TypeConverter:

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __convert__(self, thing):
       if type(thing) == list:
           return [self.convert_one(self,t) for t in thing]
       else:
           return self.convert_one(self,thing)

    def __new__(self, thing): 
        return self.__convert__(self,thing)

    @abstractmethod
    def convert_one(self, thing):
       pass

class HexToInt(TypeConverter):
    def convert_one(self, _hex):
         return int(_hex, 16)

class IntToHex(TypeConverter):
    def convert_one(self, _int):
        return hex(_int)
```

In py3 it runs fine and the objects work like functions which is the intent:

```
>>> HexToInt(['ff' , 'fe'])

[255, 254]

>>> IntToHex(255)

'0xff'
```

In py2 it does not work (but thats where I need it to work):

```
unbound method __convert__() must be called with HexToInt instance as first argument (got ABCMeta instance instead)
```

Ideally TypeConverter can hold all the some logic about whether or not to return a sequence and what type of sequence it should be etc, and the child classes implement implement some other specific logic. I dont want to have have regular function objects since id have to instantiate and then call on the object I want it to work exactly like a function; i.e does the thing when the parans close,like in the example above.

How bad of an idea is this? What are the problems here? Can I make it work even if I shouldn't?

Any and all thoughts highly appreciated.

Update, it works:

```
class TypeConverter(object):
    def __convert(this, thing):
        if type(thing) == list:
            return [this.convert_one(t) for t in thing]
        else:
            return this.convert_one( thing)

    def __new__(cls, thing):
        c = super(TypeConverter, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.__convert(c, thing)

    @abstractmethod
    def convert_one(self, thing):
        pass

class HexToInt(TypeConverter):
    def convert_one(self, _hex):
        return int(_hex, 16)

class IntToHex(TypeConverter):
    def convert_one(self, _int):
        return hex(_int)
```

Comment: `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` isn't how you set a metaclass in Python 3, by the way.

Comment: You should not use `__dunder__` methods for your own purpose, as that syntax is specifically reserved for possible future Python defined methods.

Comment: This is extremely baroque.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot simpler as a simple decorator:

```
def one_or_many(f):
    def wrapper(arg):
        if isinstance(arg, list):
            return list(map(f, arg))
        else:
            return f(arg)

    return wrapper


@one_or_many
def hex_to_int(_hex):
    return int(_hex, 16)


int_to_hex = one_or_many(hex)
```

No need for classes if you don't actually need classes.